# Mounting kubernetes volume in multiple containers within a pod with gitlab

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, minikube, persistent-volumes

I am setting up a CI/CD environment for the first time consisting of a single node kubernetes (minikube).

On this node I created a PV

```
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
data-volume   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    gitlab-managed-apps/data-volume-claim   manual                  20m
```

and PVC

```
NAME                STATUS   VOLUME        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
data-volume-claim   Bound    data-volume   1Gi        RWO            manual         19m
```

Now I would like to create a pod with multiple containers accessing to this volume.

Where and how do you advise to setup this using gitlab pipelines gitlab-ci etc? Multiple repos may be the best fit for the project.

Comment: You might run into trouble using RWO with multiple mounts. I think RWX is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fully working example of deployment manifest file, having in Pod's spec defined two containers (based on different nginx docker images) using the same PV, from where they serve custom static html content on ports 80/81 accordingly:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: my-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pv-claim-nginx
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: my-pv-storage
          subPath: html_custom 
      - image: custom-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: custom-nginx
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: my-pv-storage
          subPath: html
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes probaly you can do that run multiple container in one pod sharing the one PVC.

In CI/CD if you have multiple repos and if commit comes in one repo it will build new Docker image and push it to the registry and deployed to k8s cluster.

In CI/CD if you have the plan to use `latest` tag for image tagging then you can use multi-container in pod. it will be easy to manage deployment if there is commit in only one repository.

If you have plan to use SHA:hash for CI/CD-tagging images then how will you manage the deployment file having two containers config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How you would setup the multiple container in one pod sharing one pvc? What is the proper place to do it? gitlab-ci.yml, Dockerfile, Runners? Deploy script?

Comment: You can use 'latest' tag to tag your images and so it will be easy to fetch both from registry.while with commit hash in CI/CD it will be little hard to manage images during CD part.